Partner User Delegated External User Administrator can't activate/deactivate/edit Members
I'm facing an issue with a community user (who has the Partner Executive role in the Account hierarchy), that has the Delegated External User Administrator permission assigned to it.
This user is supposed to be able to Activate/Deactivate/Edit members of the same account, but even though he can see the buttons, errors are thrown when trying to finish that process.
Steps to reproduce

Created 6 members under the same account(2 for each Partner role).
Assigned Delegated External User Administrator permission to the 2 Executive users.
Logged in to Experience as Executive user
Went to the Account Management section and tried to Deactivate a member
Got the following error:



Tried to edit an existing member(already created user, with all details added: email, username, alias, profile, role etc).

Got the following error:


This is not because of bad page layout, because it used to work, but probably someone changed something which I'm trying to figure it out.

Already added the 


Is there anyone that might be able to help me with suggestions about what should I debug in this case? I repeat: this was working previously.

Check if the DEUA profile has View Concealed Field Data permission.
As per Salesforce Documentation

To ensure that the delegated external user administrator is set up for success, check that:
If delegated external administrators require access to personally identifiable information, such as usernames and aliases, select the View Concealed Field Data permission on the delegated external user administrator profile.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_DPUA.htm&type=5

Thanks! Didn't considered this option because in other environment it was working without this permission, but I've updated the permissions to include this one.
